How can a certificate chain be verified by two different CA certs?
I exported the certificate presented by google.com and its has chaining as "GTS Root R1" -> "GTS CA 1C3" -> "*.google.com". I put "GTS CA 1C3 + *.google.com" in inter.cer file. Then from chrome manage certificates I found "GTS Root R1" and exported it to root_ca.cer. Verifiied inter.cer with root_ca.cer and it was fine:-
% openssl verify -CAfile root_ca.cer inter.cer
inter.cer: OK

Further I have another root ca from QuoVadis called quovadis.cer ( Issuer: C=BM, O=QuoVadis Limited, CN=QuoVadis Root CA 2) and when I verified inter.crt against it it was also successful:-
% openssl verify -CAfile quovadis.cer inter.cer
inter.cer: OK

Now my question is, how can a certificate chain ( inter.cer here ) can be validated by two different root CA. Validation against "GTS Root R1" ( root_ca.cer ) I can understand but how quovadis.cer can also validate inter.cer. Both the root CA has different public keys, key idetifier etc.
I went through different article but didn't get any satisfactory answer.
EDIT: based on the comments in the answer quovadis.cer has actually multiple root CA in it: "QuoVadis Root CA 2" is the first but there is also "GTS Root R1" later.

"I went through different article" - this phrase does not provide any useful information. The only thing it shows that you did "some" research but not what research. If you want to refer to specific information you've evaluated please actually link to it.

While -CAfile adds root CA for validation, it does not remove the use of existing trusted CA. This means if the relevant CA is in the default CA store it does not matter what you give in -CAfile, i.e. it is the same as you would omit this option.
For removing the default CA from the validation process you would also need to add -no-CAfile, -no-CApath and -no-CAstore. See openssl-verification-options.

I put "GTS CA 1C3 + *.google.com" in inter.cer file.

Note that openssl verify ... inter.cer will only validated the first certificate found in the given file. In your case this is obviously "GTS CA 1C3". If it would be "*.google.com" instead the validation would instead fail.

EDIT: based on the comments in the answer quovadis.cer has actually multiple root CA in it: "QuoVadis Root CA 2" is the first but there is also "GTS Root R1" later.

Since -CAfile adds all the root CA in the given file as trusted this explains why the validation succeeds, i.e. the needed root CA "GTS Root R1" is specified as trusted.

Thanks @Steffen for quick response. I check by removing default store and path but still verification is fine for quovadis.cer :- %  openssl verify -no-CAstore -no-CApath -CAfile volterracacert.crt inter.cer
inter.cer: OK

@robocop: please first make sure that your verification fails if you add all three -no-CA* options (and not just two). Then check that verification succeeds if you add -CAfile with either one of the root CA files you want to test. Also please note that only the first certificate in inter.cer will be checked, which in your case is likely the intermediate since you've probably put it first (otherwise everything would fail). I.e. the google.com certificate will not be checked, only GTS CA 1C3. Also, what is voleracacert.crt you've used - same as quovadis.cer you claimed to use?

I got the gist of what you actually mean and behaviour is exactly same as what you predicted. %  openssl verify inter.cer
inter.cer: OK

I got the gist of what you actually mean and behaviour is exactly same as what you predicted. %  openssl verify inter.cer
inter.cer: OK ; openssl verify -no-CAfile -no-CAstore -no-CApath  -CAfile root_ca.cer inter.cer
inter.cer: OK ; openssl verify -no-CAfile -no-CAstore -no-CApath  -CAfile quovadis.cer inter.cer
inter.cer: OK ; My only doubt is how two different CA( root_ca.cer and quovadis.cer ) both can validate inter.cer. root_ca.cer is "GTS Root R1" so its fine but how a quovadis root ca is also able to validate it successfully?

@robocop: I cannot reproduce what you are doing. I get a clear failure with only -no-CA* options (you don't show your output from this) and also with -CAfile quovadis.cer and only success with -CAfile root_ca.cer. So there must be something different, like a different CA in quovadis.cer. I've used the one from https://www.quovadisglobal.com/QVRepository/DownloadRootsAndCRL/QuoVadisRootCA2-PEM/ . Or maybe some environment settings which adds some CA (that's why ensure that it fails with only -no-CA* and no -CAfile).

It's a mistake from my end that I didn't analyze quovadis.cer file completely. Its basically a collection of various root ca and quovadis root ca is just the first one. "GTS Root R1" appears somewhere down the line. It looks like openssl verifies against each root ca present in quovadis.cer one by one. Thanks for all the enlightment so far!!

@robocop: yes, -CAfile can be a collection of certificates and not just a single certificate, same like -CApath and -CAstore.
